# Seeking to arrange columns in a table via sql but retain all of the other columns

Tags: sql, datatable, ibm-midrange

All,
I'm working on an AS400 and using IBM's SQL400 DB2 SQL. I have a table with 100 columns (i.e. fields) and I need to arrange the table such that several of the columns are arranged from left to right but the remaining columns can follow the arranged columns. For example-

MyDataTable

```
LastName1  SSN2  FirstName3  Address4  Sales5  FirstVisit6  TimeofVisit7    +93 more columns
```

I need to arrange the columns/fields to look as follow-

```
FirstName3  LastName1  SSN2  FirstVisit6   TimeofVisit7   Address4  Sales5  Remaining 93 columns
```

I'm not interested in GROUP BY or ORDER by as I don't want the data sorted within the column/field but I want to arrange the columns themselves . Additionally I'm trying to avoid running SELECT of 100+ columns/fields. In essence -I have a handful of columns/fields I need to place left to right in a table and I want the remaining fields to be listed in there original place. What is the most efficient way to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `view` - you need to define the columns, but it's a one-time task.

Comment: try this...SELECT t.LastName1, t.SSN2, t.FirstName3, t.Address4, t.Sales5, t.FirstVisit6, t.TimeofVisit7, t.* FROM MyDataTable t

Answer (score 2):

I question the need for this, there's usually an opportunity to re-order the columns before presentation in the UI layer.

Unless you're just dealing with ad-hoc queries/extracts.  But even there, the Run SQL Scripts component of IBM ACS will allow you to drag & drop the columns into a new order while looking at the results.

In any case, if you're ok with duplicated columns, then @smoore4's suggestion of just selecting the ones you're interested in and then all of them is the quickest solution.

```
 SELECT t.LastName1, t.SSN2, t.FirstName3, t.Address4, t.Sales5,
        t.FirstVisit6, t.TimeofVisit7, t.* 
 FROM MyDataTable t
```

Otherwise you are going to need to list the columns in the order you want.  In order to save some typing, take a look at the QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS table

```
select system_column_name concat ', ' 
from qsys2.syscolumns syscolumns
where system_table_name = 'MYTABLE'
  and system_table_schema='MYLIB'
```

You can copy & paste the list of columns and reordered them for use in your original statement.

Lastly, note that `SELECT *` is generally a bad idea in any kind of production code.  You may find the SQL statements I posted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803398/sqlrpgle-is-there-something-wrong-with-my-sql-query/67807099#67807099) of some use for building lists of columns.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to type all the columns in a large table, I use a DB2 function named `listagg()`.  It looks like this:

```
select listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by ordinal_position)
from qsys2.syscolumns
where table_schema = 'library name'
  and table_name = 'table name'
```

Just make sure you type your library and table names in all upper case. It will give you a comma separated string of column names. If the string is longer than 4000 characters (which can happen if your table has a lot of fields) then you can tell the function to return a larger field by casting the column larger like this:

```
select listagg(cast(column_name as varchar(8000)), ', ') within group (order by ordinal_position)
from qsys2.syscolumns
where table_schema = 'library name'
  and table_name = 'table name'
```

This will produce a varchar(8000) result field. You can safely cast it all the way up to 32740, but if you do that, there can be no other columns on the row since the max row length without large objects is 32740.

**Note:** this is the SQL column name. To get the 10 character system name, you want to use `trim(system_column_name)` instead of `column_name`. The trim is important here as system column name is defined as char(10) vs. varchar(128), and will include trailing spaces unless they are trimmed off.

Comment: would be very useful if DB2 allowed user defined aggregate functions.   In this case, a user defined aggregate function could create the entire SQL create table command string. [Stored Aggregate Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-aggregate-functions/)

Comment: Given that the only required list in the CREATE TABLE function is the column list, It would be rather simple to generate an entire CREATE TABLE function in an SQL statement. just wrap the LISTAGG function with 'CREATE TABLE xxxxxx (' and ')'

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to rearrange the columns in a table?

here is an SQL function named `alterTable_addColumn_likeColumn` that will add a column to a table that has the same data definition as a column in a reference table. The purpose being you can use this function in a `select from syscolumns` SQL statement to add all the columns from the table you want to rearrange to a new table.

The `alterTable_addColumn_likeColumn` SQL function:

```
/* add a column to a table with the same data defn as the like   */
/* column.                                                       */

CREATE OR REPLACE function  alterTable_addColumn_likeColumn(
inSchema  char(10),
inTableName  char(80),
inColumnName char(80),
inLikeSchema  char(10),
inLikeTable   char(80),
inLIkeColumn  char(80))
returns    char(80)
language sql
specific     core0066f
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SET OPTION  datfmt = *ISO,   DLYPRP = *YES, DBGVIEW = *SOURCE,
            USRPRF = *OWNER, DYNUSRPRF = *OWNER
BEGIN

DECLARE     VMSG CHAR(80) ;
DECLARE     VCMDSTR CHAR(256) ;
declare     vSqlCode decimal(5,0) default 0 ;
declare     vSqlState char(5) default ' ' ;
declare     vErrText char(256) default ' ' ;
declare     sqlCode int default 0 ;
declare     SqlState char(5) default ' ' ;
declare     vDataType char(10) default ' ' ;
declare     vLength decimal(5,0) default 0 ;
declare     vDprc   decimal(1,0) default 0 ;
declare     vNullable char(1) default ' ' ;
declare     vHasDefault     char(1)   default ' ' ;
declare     vColumnDefault  char(80)  default ' ' ;
declare     vColumnHeading  char(80)  default ' ' ;
declare     vStmt  char(2000) default ' ' ;
declare     dataDefn  varchar(80) default ' ' ;
declare     vNotNull  varchar(80) default '' ;
declare     vDataDefn varchar(80) default '' ;
declare     vDefault  varchar(256)  default '' ;
declare     errmsg char(256)   default ' ' ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
begin
SET     vSqlCode  = SQLCODE ;
SET     vSqlState = SQLstate ;
get     diagnostics exception 1 vErrText = message_text ;
end ;

/* check for add column already exist.            */
select   a.length
into     vLength
from     qsys2/syscolumns a
where    a.table_schema = inSchema and a.table_name = inTableName
         and a.column_name = inColumnName ;
if       sqlcode = 0 then
return   trim(inColumnName) || ' exists' ;
end if ;

/* read data defn of like column.           */
select   a.data_type,
         decimal(a.length,5,0) length,
         decimal(coalesce(numeric_scale,0),3,0) dprc,
         a.is_nullable, a.has_default,
         char(a.column_default,50) column_default, a.column_heading
into     vDataType, vLength, vDprc,
         vNullable, vHasDefault,
         vColumnDefault, vColumnHeading
from     qsys2/syscolumns a
where    a.table_schema = inLikeSchema and a.table_name = inLikeTable
         and a.column_name = inLikeColumn ;

/* data defn of the column.   */
if          vDataType = 'CHAR' or vDataType = 'VARCHAR' then
set         vDataDefn = trim(vDataType) || '(' || trim(char(vLength)) || ')' ;
elseif      vDataType in ('DATE','TIME','TIMESTAMP') then
set         vDataDefn = trim(vDataType) ;
else
set         vDataDefn = trim(vDataType) || '(' || trim(char(vLength)) ||
                       ',' || trim(char(vDprc)) || ')' ;
end if;

/* is nullable.     */
if          vNullable = 'N' then
set         vNotNull = 'not null ' ;
else
set         vNotNull = '' ;
end if ;

/* default value.  */
if          vHasDefault = 'Y' then
set         vDefault = 'default ' || trim(vColumnDefault) ;
end if ;

set         vStmt   = 'alter table ' || trim(inSchema) || '/' ||
                      trim(inTableName) || ' ' ||
                      'add column ' || trim(inColumnName) || ' ' ||
                      vDataDefn || ' ' || vNotNull ||
                      ' ' || vDefault ;

prepare     s1 from vStmt ;
execute     s1 ;

return      trim(inColumnName) || ' added' ;

END
```

to use the function, start with a new table:

```
create table  qgpl/steve18 (                            
 CREATETIME timestamp default current_timestamp )
```

run the `select * from syscolumns` query. Specify the `alterTable_addColumn_likeColumn` function as one of the select columns. This runs the function against every row selected from the `SYSCOLUMNS` table. The end result is to have columns added to the definition of the target table.

```
select   char(a.column_name,20) colname, a.data_type,            
         decimal(a.length,5,0) length,                           
         decimal(coalesce(numeric_scale,0),3,0) dprc,            
         a.system_column_name,                                   
         altertable_addColumn_likeColumn( 'QGPL','STEVE18',    
              a.column_name, a.table_schema, a.table_name,       
              a.column_name) addcol                              
from     qsys2/syscolumns a                                      
where    a.table_schema = 'MYLIB' and a.table_name = 'CUSMS'
```